# Add unique ids to serialized objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have an `owner` model that saves a serialized array of `item` objects to a text field in the database. I can add items to this array easily enough, but when I want to remove one I cannot because there is no unique identifier for each object.

Is there a readily available approach to solving this or do I need to implement some kind of unique ID generator?

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :items
end

class Item
  attr_accessor :name
end

owner = Owner.new
owner.items = []
owner.items << Item.new(name: 'Test')
owner.save
```

In the `show` view for an `owner` the items are listed, and I want to include a `remove item` link, but have no way to identify the item.

```
for each item...
<%= link_to 'Remove Item', remove_item_path(item) %> # item won't match after owner is reloaded in the controller

# controller
owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
owner.items.delete(params[:item]) # This won't work, items have been reloaded when owner was found
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can't you use association instead? Serializing is good for small variables (array, hash) not for records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with adding a random key to each object in the initialize method.

```
def initialize(options = {})
  self.filterid = SecureRandom.base64(32)
  ...
end
```